# Variable is returning as NaN in js

Tags: javascript, html, tween

I am rotating a model. When I click start button it starts from `0`

`start = animateAssembly`

I am trying to resume from `width`. What ever value of `width` will be there my animation will start from there.

`resume = resumeAssembly`

but width variable returning as `NaN` inside frame.

and not getting passed into `resumeAssembly`

```
animateAssembly: function() {

        var element = document.getElementById("myBar");

        this.width = 1;

        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = setInterval(frame, 100);

        //here my width shows number
        console.log(typeof this.width);

        function frame() {
            if (this.width >= 100) {
                console.log(typeof this.width);
                clearInterval(this.interval);
            } else {
                this.width++;
                console.log(typeof parseInt(this.width));
                console.log(typeof this.width);

                //here it shows as NaN
                element.style.width = parseInt(this.width) + '%';
                element.innerHTML = parseInt(this.width) + "%";

            }
        }

    },


    pauseAssembly: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.tweening.stop();

    },


    resumeAssembly: function() {
        var element = document.getElementById("myBar");
        element.style.width = this.width + '%';
        element.innerHTML = this.width + "%";

    },
```

Comment: Definitely relevant (maybe a duplicate): [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a function scope problem.
Inside your frame, probably `this` doesn't refer what you think.
It's probably targeting `interval` itself.
So while giving function

```js
this.interval = setInterval(frame.bind(this), 100); // bind current target
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. And learned something new too.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in your function `frame()` refers to the context of the `frame()` function, not of the parent function in which you initialized `this.width`

To avoid this, you can initialize your frame function as an arrow function:

```js
const frame = () => {
    // here, 'this' refers to the parent's scope
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside  `function frame()` you have a different `this`. Either use arrow syntax

`const frame = () => {}`

or change calling site.

```
this.interval = setInterval(frame.bind(this), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is scope problem when you are accessing `this.width` inside `function frame()`. Because `this` inside `frame` is different that `this` inside `animateAssembly`.

So When `frame` function getting executed then `this.width` will be `undefined`. So `parseInt(undefined)` will be `NaN`.

This can be solved in two different ways

- Use arrow function in order have same `this` inside `frame` function as well like below

```
const frame = () => {
    //rest of the code
}
```

- You can `bind` the function to have same reference for `this` like below

```
this.interval = setInterval(frame.bind(this), 100);
```

Hope this helps.